# rpmrebuild creates broken SPEC file

Tags: linux, rpm

`rpmrebuild` seems to create a broken SPEC file, even if I don't actually change anything.  I do the following:

```
[build@admin slurm]$ EDITOR=emacs rpmrebuild -enp slurm-19.05.5-1.el7.src.rpm 
Do you want to continue ? (y/N) y
error: File must begin with "/": slurm-19.05.5.tar.bz2
error: File must begin with "/": slurm.spec
    File must begin with "/": slurm-19.05.5.tar.bz2
    File must begin with "/": slurm.spec
/usr/lib/rpmrebuild/rpmrebuild.sh: ERROR: package 'slurm-19.05.5-1.el7.src.rpm' build failed
[build@admin slurm]$ EDITOR=emacs rpmrebuild -enp slurm-19.05.5-1.el7.src.rpm 
Do you want to continue ? (y/N) y
error: File must begin with "/": slurm-19.05.5.tar.bz2
error: File must begin with "/": slurm.spec
    File must begin with "/": slurm-19.05.5.tar.bz2
    File must begin with "/": slurm.spec
/usr/lib/rpmrebuild/rpmrebuild.sh: ERROR: package 'slurm-19.05.5-1.el7.src.rpm' build failed
```

I assume that the paths must be specified absolutely.  As I say, this error occurs even if I don't edit the file at all.

I'm using version 2.11.  Does anyone know what the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `rpmbuild --rebuild` to rebuild a source package, not `rpmrebuild`.

## rpmrebuild

> rpmrebuild is a tool to build an RPM file from a package that has
>   already been installed in a basic use, rpmrebuild use do not require
>   any rpm building knowledge (On debian, the equivalent product is
>   dpkg-repack)

## rpmbuild --rebuild

> When  invoked this way, rpmbuild installs the named source package,
>   and does a prep, compile and install.  In addition, --rebuild builds a
>   new binary package. When the build has completed, the build
>          directory is removed (as in --clean) and the the sources and spec file for the package are removed.

Comment: I want to rebuild an RPM from a SRPM, but with a modified spec file (just adding an option to 'configure').  Is '--rebuild' still the way to go?  The relevant section of man page is rather short.  Do I have to redefine the '%configure' macro in a local macro file?  And if so, can I just add the option like '%configure --with-bells-and-whistles' or do I need to get the current value of '%configure' and then add '--with-bells-and-whistles' to that?

Comment: in that case, first install the src.rpm: `rpm -i src.rpm`, then edit the spec file manually (inside ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/), then run `rpmbuild -ba the.spec`